# at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2885)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-navigation

I build navigation drawer and it's successfully installed in mobile also but after click the button application automatically stopped. but it's not showing any error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.adworld.admin.ab, PID: 25835
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adworld.admin.ab/com.adworld.admin.ab.Main2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2932)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3010)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1707)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6758)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:557)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at com.adworld.admin.ab.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7147)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7138)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2885)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3010) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1707) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6758) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:557) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
```

Comment: `CollapsingToolbarLayout` cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar... Thats telling you what the problem is. It can't find the right type, it can't cast `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `widget.Toolbar`. Go to the layout and ensure the type is correct and recompile.

Comment: i unable to run my application in mobile but it's not showing any error in android studio:

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are casting the CollapsingToolbar. It can be a `findViewById`

Comment: @PatrickDark Post the code from `Main2Activity.class` if you can, or maybe just the start of the class all way to `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
     com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot be cast 
     to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

check your JAVA code where you have defined the Toolbar and Convert it to com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 1):

`CollapsingToolbarLayout` cannot be cast to `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...` Thats telling you what the problem is.

It can't find the right type, it can't cast `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `widget.Toolbar`

Go to the layout for `Main2Activity`, incase you are not sure what i'm referring to:
[image]

In the layout, switch to `Text` mode; press button on bottom left.

Make sure that you defined `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` and the `id` you gave it it's the one you are using in your `Main2Activity.class`'s `findViewById`. Check example below obtained from https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Using the example above, we care about this line in order to do our cast on `Main2Activity`: `android:id="@+id/app_bar"`

It would then look something like this within `onCreate()`:

`AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);`